# Updating multiple records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to update multiple records in my table so im wondering if there´s something wrong in this script as im only getting updated the last record.. this is the complete code http://pastie.org/5453954

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['id_servtype']); $i++){

    $servtype = $_POST['id_servtype'][$i];    
    $project = $_POST['id_project'][$i];
    $quantity = $_POST['tableQuantity'][$i];
    $pus = $_POST['tablePus'][$i];
    $puc = $_POST['tablePuc'][$i];
    $totalitem = $_POST['tableTotal'][$i];

    $sql = "update sales_order_items
    set
    id_project=?,
    id_service_type=?,
quantity=?,
    unit_price_no_tax=?,
    unit_price=?,
    total_item_imp=?
    where
    id_so=?
    and
    id_soitems=?
    ";

    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $project, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $servtype, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(3, $quantity, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(4, $pus, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(5, $puc, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(6, $totalitem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(7, $_POST["id"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(8, $_POST["iditem"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    }

    echo("Correct edition");
```

Comment: try printing out $_POST['id_servtype'] to see what you are iterating through maybe its not what you think it should be

Comment: I have just printed out and im getting the same value on each row no matter what i change.. this is happening with  $servtype = $_POST['id_servtype']; and   
    $project = $_POST['id_project'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with your logic: the values used in your `WHERE` clause are always the same, so you're always updating *all* records, each time using new values.
Logically, when your script has finished, only the last update will be visible, all previous updates have been overwritten. A simple example:

```
$newVals = array(1,2,3);
while($val = array_shift($newVals))
{
    $query = 'UPDATE myDB.tbl SET someField = :val WHERE id = 1';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array('val' => $val));
}
```

Is the same as writing:

```
UPDATE myDB.tbl SET someField = 1 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE myDB.tbl SET someField = 2 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE myDB.tbl SET someField = 3 WHERE id = 1;
```

So the record(s) with id 1 are updated a total of three times, each time undoing the last update

Comment: What do you mean by "always the same". I need the id and the iditem value in order to update those records. Im getting the id via _GET

Comment: @user1763639: in the example above think of `$newVals` as one of your `$_POST` arrays, and the hard-codded `1` as a `GET` id. Every time you pass through the loop, you update the same record

Comment: @user1763639: By _always the same_ I mean that, for every UPDATE query in the loop, the WERE clause will be the same: only 1 GET variable is used over and over. I didn't mean to say that every request will update the same records as any other request - just that every request will update the records, specified by the where clause multiple times

Comment: How can i get the correct value linked to the correct member so i can update correctly?

Comment: Either pass the distict id's as an array, like all the other values, or pass them all through GET parameters (not recommended, obviously). I don't know how your data is structured and what you're updating, and thus can't tell you what will be the easiest way to update what data, but just don't use the same WHERE clause for multiple update's, or you'll update them all several times